# Jupyter nootebook: Can I mark a code cell as do not execute (skip code cell)?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab

I am running a .iypnb for building an ML model. The execution time takes more than 2 hrs. I wanted to know if I can mark a code cell as "Do not execute" so that the notebook can skip over it. However, I would like to preserve the previous output for that particular cell.